# How to Split Columns in R based on First Space

Tags: r, regex, string, regex-lookarounds

I have this code that splits the column on the second space, but I don't know how to modify it to split on the first space only. I'm not that familiar with regex.

```
library(tidyr)

df <- data.frame(Location = c("San Jose CA", "Fremont CA", "Santa Clara CA"))
separate(df, Location, into = c("city", "state"), sep = " (?=[^ ]+$)")

#          city state
# 1    San Jose    CA
# 2     Fremont    CA
# 3 Santa Clara    CA
```

Comment: If you really need to split on the _first_ space, then I suggest editing your question to reflect this.  Your current question seeks to separate city from state, which requires splitting on the _last_ space.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use

```r
library(tidyr)
df <- data.frame(Location = c("San Jose CA", "Fremont CA", "Santa Clara CA"))
df_new <- separate(df, Location, into = c("city", "state"), sep = "^\\S*\\K\\s+")
```

Output:

```
> df_new
     city      state
1     San    Jose CA
2 Fremont         CA
3   Santa   Clara CA
```

The `^\S*\K\s+` regex matches

- `^` - start of string
- `\S*` - zero or more non-whitespace chars
- `\K` - match reset operator that discards the text matched so far from the overall match memory buffer
- `\s+`  - one or more whitespace chars.

**NOTE**: If your strings can have leading whitespace, and you want to ignore this leading whitespace, you can add `\\s*` right after `^` and use

```
sep = "^\\s*\\S+\\K\\s+"
```

Here, `\S+` will require at least one (or more) non-whitespace chars to exist before the whitespaces that the string is split with.

Comment: Perfect, thanks! And thanks for explaining about regex which I'm trying to learn about.

Comment: Hi, I realize this was a while ago, but what is the reason for the double backlash (\\) instead of the single backslash (\)?

Comment: @ra_learns A backslash in string literals is used to define string escape sequences, like `\n` for a newline, line feed char, and the `\t` sequence defines a TAB char. Hence, a ``\\`` is used to define a single ``\`` char.

Comment: thank you very much. If someone is looking to split using the last space you can use this regex = ' (?=[^ ]+$)'

Answer (score 1):

If you want to stick with `separate`, then try:

```r
separate(df, Location, into=c("city", "state"), sep=" (?=[A-Z]{2}$)")
```

We can also try using `sub` here for a base R option:

```r
df$city <- sub("\\s+[A-Z]{2}$", "", df$Location)
df$state <- sub("^.*\\s+", "", df$Location)
```

Comment: Thanks but that gave the same result. It separates on the 2nd space. I want to separate on the first space.

Comment: @CrashBandicoot [Check this demo](https://regex101.com/r/ODddU2/1) to see that the `sep` I used in the `separate` call is targeting the correct second space.  Are you sure you want to split on the _first_ space?

Comment: yeah it's the first space I need to target. I know it doesn't make much sense in the context of this example